# how to create dynamicly generated button that call server side method in using javascript in ASP.Net c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**My problem**
1) I created aspx page and put literal on it.
2) In .cs file->fetch data from db and bind it on literal
e.g
literal is that control
then

```
 literal+="<tr><td>data goes here</td><td>here i want put my button</td></tr>"
```

then how to raise click event from html control .

```
**.aspx page**

<div class="table-primary">
            <table>
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>#</th>
                       <td>Sales Person</td>
                       <td>Employee Code</td>
                       <td>Status</td>
                       <td>Action</td>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

.cs page

```
protected void BindData()
{
    int i = 0;
    DataTable dt = VijayDB.ExecuteSqlQueryForDataTable(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SFA_GetAllSalesPerson", null);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Literal1.Text += "<tr>";
        Literal1.Text += "<td>"+(i++)+"</td>";
        Literal1.Text += "<td>" + dr["person_name"] + "</td>";
        Literal1.Text += "<td>" + dr["fk_hrme_employee_id"] + "</td>";
        Literal1.Text += "<td>" + dr["person_status"] + "</td>";
        Literal1.Text += "<td><a href='javascript:Edit(" + dr["pk_sfa_stm_salesperson_id"] + ");'>Edit</td>";
        Literal1.Text += "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use [GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/851092/ASP-NET-GridView-CRUD-Operations) instead of literal. [Example1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/how-to-bind-gridview-in-3-tier-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp/)

Comment: i grid view when i perform curd operation that the its need to re bind grid again n again, i don't want do this. i want when i perform curd only that row will be affected for that i want to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you could create an event ahead of time without binding it to the control (since it does not exist yet). then, in your code, after dynamically generating the control, you could use AddHandler method to add the event to the button click event

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Text = "New Button"; 
btn.ID = "Button1"; 
btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.NewButton_Click);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
Literal1.Text += "<td><a href='#' onServerClick='Save'  runat='server'>Edit</a></td>";
```

and it render

```
<td><a href='#' onServerClick='Save'  runat='server'>Edit</a></td>
```

but when i write `<a href='#' onServerClick='Save'  runat='server'>Edit</a>` in aspx page it rendes

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Body$ctl01','')">Edit</a>
```

and this working fine.

so how to render literal text to generate above html